CSS | Creating a custom shape for a sidebar or side frame
I have an application that has this design. The white sidebar should look exactly like in the pic which has an irregular shape. I need some CSS wizard to help me figure out how to make it happen.


This question is either too broad or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Please add below code
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

CSS :-
 .container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh; 
}

.sidebar {
    width: 300px; 
    background: white;
    clip-path: path("M 0 0 H 300 V 600 C 150 600 150 400 300 400 V 0 H 0 Z");
    z-index: 2;
}

.content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: #004d40;
    padding: 20px;
}


You're right that the polygon function in CSS doesn't support curves, my apologies for the oversight. Instead, we can use the clip-path with a path() function, which allows for more complex shapes including curves. I will update my code.
